# Will upgrading to 4GB RAM on a white MacBook work?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, upgrade

I've seen discussions about upgrading memory but it was only for the MacBook Pro. I have a white 13" MacBook with 2GB memory, I'm considering about upgrading the memory to 4GB.

Is it possible to upgrade the memory from 2GB to 4GB with the white MacBook (late 2009)?

Comment: The stores mentioned in the following linked question sell memory for (almost) all Macs, including your white MacBook: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5994/where-are-good-places-to-buy-ram-memory-for-a-mac

Comment: @nathan The question being asked here regarding the 2GB to 4GB upgradability of the MacBook isn't answered by the linked duplicate. I think you were too quick on the trigger to close the question.

Comment: @Negrino I guess you're right; that part is a legitimate question on its own. Reopened and edited.

Comment: @Negrino actually, it **is** answered. It links right to OWC memory upgrades. From there it's a matter of choosing White Macbook… for the lazy, here's the link: http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/Apple_MacBook_MacBook_Pro/Upgrade/Macbook_selector

Comment: I know that the MacBook6,*n* series is listed as being able to take up to 8GB. Click **More Info...** on About This Mac to find your Model Identifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All white Macbooks can certainly be upgraded to 4 and -in some cases- 6GB of RAM.

Depending upon your model, you should check [OWC's Memory Upgrades](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/Apple_MacBook_MacBook_Pro/Upgrade) and go from there. I believe other vendors (Crucial, Newegg, etc.) will have similar pages with similar info (and similar prices). I've brought different memory upgrades from OWC and never had a single failure so far.

I have an old Macbook 4.1 White Core 2 Duo 2.4 and can go up to 6GB. So best thing to do is check your exact Macbook model and see what they offer.

Comment: Note: The first gen MacBooks with a Core Duo processor could not address more than 2GB of Ram as noted here http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook_2.0_white.html so the blanket statement does not really cover all white MacBooks.

Answer (score 1):

How to upgrade RAM memory on MacBook White a1342
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xS6STfKdYFU

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you have the MacBook 6,1 also known as the "Unibody" - Late 2009 you can upgrade to 4GB. Additionally you can max it out to as much as 8GB if you would like as noted in [everymac's specs for the late 2009 MacBook Unibody](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.26-white-13-polycarbonate-unibody-late-2009-specs.html).

> Standard RAM:  2 GB    Maximum RAM:    8 GB*
>
> Details:   2 GB of RAM is installed as two 1 GB modules, no slots free.
>
> *Apple officially supports a maximum of 4 GB of RAM, but third-parties have confirmed that it actually supports 8 GB of RAM.